# Input value not long enough for date format

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to show week numbers on a query. I have the following sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(TRUNC((sysdate + ROWNUM), 'IW'), 'IW' ) as dt 
  FROM DUAL 
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= (2-1)*7
```

when I try to execute it it gives me the following error: `input value not long enough for date format` I know this is a common error but I can't find an solution to my answer.

It returns the following when I do it witouth to_char: `20/02/2017 00:00:00`

Comment: Why both trunc and to_char? Couldn't to_char be enough?

Comment: I'll test that.

Comment: It gives me the same error.

Comment: Which version of the database are you using? Posted code works for me (on 12c)

Comment: `TO_CHAR(sysdate + ROWNUM, 'IW')` should be enough. And `to_char(...'IW')` will **never** return `20/02/2017 00:00:00` it only returns the week number, not a complete date. Are you sure that you showed us the code that you run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this works:

`SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(TRUNC((SYSDATE) + (ROWNUM), 'IW'), 'IW') as dt
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= (3-1)*7`

don't really know what changed but it works now.